# Security of Excel Encryption

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with lots of passwords of online accounts on.

It was encrypted in Excel 2013 as per this doc:
https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Protect-your-document-workbook-or-presentation-with-passwords-permission-and-other-restrictions-05084cc3-300d-4c1a-8416-38d3e37d6826

Unfortunately I was carrying the file on a USB stick and lost it. Someone found it and gave it back to me by leaving it in the building I left it in, and left it in an envelope and texted me to confirm, as I left a note in the building I lost it in with my mobile number on.

The file contains hundreds of passwords for lots of different websites.

I am worried he may be able to hack the password somehow, but looking online, it looks like it might not be so easy to hack an excel file which is encrypted, rather than an excel file which one can open, but whose contents are password protected.

I wondered if anyone has any views on this (apart from views on my obvious stupidity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file has a strong password than it will be unlikely to hack. But a weak and common password can be hacked easily. There are online databases with passwords that can process your file and if the password is in that database the file can de decrypted.